# Musikalischer Sinn von "Gang"

Tags: word-usage

Bei Novalis habe ich das Wort "Gang" in einem musikalischen Kontext gelesen

> [Er] griff so selbst in den Saiten nach Tönen und **Gängen** umher"

https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/novalis/sais/sais.html

Das Deutsches Wörterbuch der Brüder Grimm hat folgende Belege:

> - *einige gänge auf dem claviere machen*: ein paar mal die scala auf und ab spielen (Adelung)
> - *einen gang machen*, ein stück oder eine stelle spielen. *Louise: wollen sie mich accompagniren, herr von Walther, so mach ich einen
>   gang auf dem fortepiano.* (Schiller) In Louisens worten ist der
>   gehende deutlich noch sie selber, aber der begriff gieng auch auf die
>   töne selbst über.

http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=Gang

Beim Duden findet man diesen Sinn nicht. Aus Neugier möchte ich wissen, ob dieser Sinn des Wortes heute total unverständlich geworden ist oder von einem (eventuell musikalisch gebildeten) Deutschmuttersprachler hergeleitet werden kann.

Comment: Ich habe das noch nie gehört oder gelesen; interessant finde ich, dass es *Lauf* als musikalischen Begriff gibt, siehe [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauf_(Musik)) oder [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Lauf) allerdings erst unter Nummer 7. Ob das der Nachfolgebegriff für dieselbe Sache ist, kann ich nicht sagen.

Comment: @guidot: Ein Lauf ist natürlich schneller als ein Gang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meyers [Konversationslexikon](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/schlagwort.html?wort=Gang&werk=Meyers) von 1885-1892 kennt den Begriff als:

> Gang (franz. Passage), eine in gleichen Noten laufende Tonfigur von längerer (mehrtaktiger) Ausdehnung. Man unterscheidet skalenartige und Akkordgänge (Arpeggien) sowie aus beiden zusammengesetzte. Ein G. hält gewöhnlich eine melodische Figur fest.

Ich kann mir nur schwer vorstellen, dass diese Bedeutung bei heutigen Lesern ankommt oder erschlossen werden kann.

Comment: Eigentlich ist es nicht schwierig, die Bedeutung zu erschließen. Zum einen ist es schlicht die Kurzform für *Durchgang*, was wir ja heute noch im Sinne von *Durchlauf* oder *Wiederholung* verwenden; zum anderen wird *Gang* auch außerhalb der Musik verwendet, zum Beispiel wenn es um die Gänge eines Menüs, das heißt um die Speisenfolge (anstelle der Tonfolge) geht.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Dass "Gang" nun ausgerechnet eine in *gleichen* Noten laufende Tonfolge ist, kann man sich nicht erschließen. Dass es aber wohl irgendeine Tonfolge bzw. ein Durchspielvorgang derselben ist, sicherlich.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, ich glaube, hier liegt ein Missverständnis bei der Interpretation der Definition vor. Mit *gleichen Noten* ist gemeint, dass, wenn *der gleiche Gang*, zum Beispiel der Refrain, nochmal kommt, *die gleichen Noten* gespielt werden (oder beim Menü *die gleichen Speisen* serviert werden). Es ist sicherlich nicht gemeint, dass alle Gänge die gleiche Noten hätten. Ebenso bei *Passage*, die als Synonym in Klammern steht: Wenn *die gleiche Passage* noch einmal gespielt wird, werden *die gleichen Noten* gespielt; gleichwohl bestehen nicht alle Passagen eines Stücks aus den gleichen Noten.

Comment: Die oben beschriebenen Dinge heißen heutzutage "Lauf" bzw. "Läufe", was oft verwendet wird. "Gang" sagt keiner dazu (siehe meine Antwort).

Answer (score -2):

"Einen Gang machen" kennt man aus Büchern des 18./19. Jahrhunderts, wo man dann normalerweise meint, dass man sich auf den Weg macht, um Dinge zu erledigen. Ich würde sagen, es war auch noch in der ersten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts im süddeutschen Raum geläufig, aber da bin ich mir nicht sicher.

Heutzutage kenne ich es nur noch in aktiver Verwendung bei der Floskel "einen Botengang machen".

In Bezug auf Musik habe ich es bisher noch nie gehört, und obwohl ich kein Profi in Bezug auf klassische Musik bin, möchte ich behaupten, das auch noch nie in diesem Bereich gehört zu haben, dass das dort jemand so noch sagt. Wahrscheinlich hat man das früher von der allgemeinen Verwendung auch auf die Musik ausgeweitet, und es ist dann insgesamt überall als Phrase wieder aus der Mode gekommen.

Von der Verständlichkeit her kann man es (mit dem Wissen, wie "einen Gang machen" früher so gebräuchlich war) ableiten, was damit wohl gemeint ist, aber es klingt sehr fremd und ungewöhnlich.

Nachtrag: Was oft verwendet wird, ist der Begriff "Lauf", eine Abfolge von Tönen oder Akkorden. "Gang" sagt aber keiner dazu.